# ExtJS, How can i use hbox inside Fieldset

Tags: javascript, extjs

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8Pqtx/

I have the hbox code working outside fieldset

```
{
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [{
        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
        name: 'first',
        allowBlank: false
    }, {
        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
        name: 'last'
    }]
}
```

But inside fieldset it shows one textbox with nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get fields with hbox layout you can't apply `layout:'hbox'` in fieldset. Instead you can create a container as an item in fieldset with `layout:'hbox'`

```
items: [{
            xtype:'fieldset',
            columnWidth: 0.8,
            title: 'Fieldset 1',
            collapsible: true,
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
            layout: 'anchor',
            items :[{
                layout: 'hbox',
                xtype:"container",
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype:"textfield",
                        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                        name: 'first',
                        allowBlank: false
                    }, {
                        xtype:"textfield",
                        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                        name: 'last'
                    }
                ]
           }]
        }]
```

For reference: http://jsfiddle.net/hWGYE/2929/

Answer (score 0):

Hi i have done some changes in your code,and it is rendering properly.

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                title: 'Simple Form with FieldSets',
                labelWidth: 75, // label settings here cascade unless overridden
                url: 'save-form.php',
                frame: true,
                bodyStyle: 'padding:5px 5px 0',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                layout: 'column', // arrange fieldsets side by side
                items: [{
                    // Fieldset in Column 1 - collapsible via toggle button
                    xtype:'fieldset',
                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                    title: 'Fieldset 1',
                    collapsible: true,
                    defaultType: 'textfield',
                    defaults: {anchor: '100%'},
                    layout: 'anchor',
                    items :[{
                        fieldLabel: 'Field 1',
                        name: 'field1'
                    }, {
                        fieldLabel: 'Field 2',
                        name: 'field2'
                    },

                           {
                                    layout: 'hbox',
                                    xtype:"container",
                                    items: [
                                    {
                                        xtype:"textfield",
                                        fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                                        name: 'first',
                                        allowBlank: false
                                    }, {
                                        xtype:"textfield",
                                        fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                                        name: 'last'
                                    }
                                            ]
                                }]
                }, ]
            });
  });
```